# AWS change the character encoding of EB EC2 instance log files

Tags: amazon-web-services, character-encoding

At my work we have a Django application deployed on an Elastic Beanstalk Linux instance. Much of the text on the website is in Japanese, which leads to text in the error logs not being shown correctly (like \xe6). The character encoding of the log files is ASCII, so I need to change it to UTF-8 or Shift-JIS. Any ideas on how to do so?

I tried changing the metadata for the logs saved in the S3 bucket, Content-type = text/plain; utf8 (also tried shift-jis), however upon downloading the file it still had the ASCII format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I haven't, been busy with other tasks. Should be able to get back to it within a few weeks.